Unable to run Python Behave on Gitlab Pipeline
I'm having issues running my Behave Python and Playwright tests on Gitlab. Whenever i try to call the Behave function to run my test scripts, which works fine locally, they won't run on the Gitlab pipeline.
Below is the error it throws:
$ behave features
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/bin/behave", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 183, in main
    return run_behave(config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 127, in run_behave
Exception KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
    failed = runner.run()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 804, in run
    return self.run_with_paths()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 809, in run_with_paths
    self.load_step_definitions()
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 796, in load_step_definitions
    load_step_modules(step_paths)
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/runner_util.py", line 412, in load_step_modules
    exec_file(os.path.join(path, name), step_module_globals)
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/behave/runner_util.py", line 386, in exec_file
    exec(code, globals_, locals_)
  File "features/steps/DataSourcePubSubSteps.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pages.RDM_DatasourcesPage import RDM_DatasourcesPage
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/pages/RDM_DatasourcesPage.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/builds/rail-delivery-group/quasar_automation/rdm/rdg-qa-raildatamarketplace-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
                       ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 714, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

The tests themselves run in headless mode, so they shouldn't need a display or mouse to run. Not too sure how to fix or run this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

One of your steps requires PyAutoGUI, which requires a display, as in: it doesn't run on pure console. You might be able to use a virtual framebuffer (xvfb).

Ah thank you. So is it that specific area that's causing problems? How do i go about using the XVFB?

Sorry for an extra comment - Looks as though i had PyautoGUI imported but ended up not using it. Removed it and it seems to have fixed the problem!
